# determine if $G = \{ f : \mathbb{R_+} \to \mathbb{R_+} \}$ is a group

Tags: group-theory

[image]

I'm confused about how the identity was formed - if $e(x) = x$, then how does one get from $f(x)e(x) = f(x)\cdot 1$

Comment: The authors are wrong. You are correct.

Comment: There appears to be a typo. They meant $e(x)=1$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. The book seems to have a typo - they probably meant to define $e(x)=1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}_{+}$.